# Rails has_many with dynamic conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

What I want is to create a Model that connects with another using a has_many association in a dynamic way, without the foreign key like this:

```
has_many :faixas_aliquotas, :class_name => 'Fiscal::FaixaAliquota',
            :conditions => ["regra_fiscal = ?", ( lambda { return self.regra_fiscal } ) ]
```

But I get the error:

```
: SELECT * FROM "fis_faixa_aliquota" WHERE ("fis_faixa_aliquota".situacao_fiscal_id = 1
AND (regra_fiscal = E'--- !ruby/object:Proc {}'))
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

#### Rails 4+ way (Thanks to Thomas who answered this below):

```
has_many :faixas_aliquotas, -> (object) { 
           where("regra_fiscal = ?", object.regra_fiscal)
         },
         :class_name => 'Fiscal::FaixaAliquota'
```

#### Rails 3.1+ way:

```
has_many :faixas_aliquotas, :class_name => 'Fiscal::FaixaAliquota',
         :conditions => proc { "regra_fiscal = #{self.regra_fiscal}" }
```

#### Rails 3 and below:

```
has_many :faixas_aliquotas, :class_name => 'Fiscal::FaixaAliquota',
         :conditions => ['regra_fiscal = #{self.regra_fiscal}']
```

No. This is not a mistake. The conditions are specified in single quotes and still contains the code `#{self.regra_fiscal}`. When the conditions clause is evaulated, the regra_fiscal method will be called on the object of `self` (whatever the class is). Putting double quotes will not work.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: +1 Just tried, and got: 
>> SituacaoFiscal.last.faixas_aliquotas
NameError: uninitialized constant SituacaoFiscal
 from /home/fabiano/workspace/sgi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
 from /home/fabiano/workspace/sgi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
 from /home/fabiano/workspace/sgi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing' 
likely because my class name is: 'Fiscal::SituacaoFiscal'

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle the scope, you might want to try some stuff around this solution.

Comment: Worked perfectly now! Likely I was doing something wrong in my class before; tnxs!

Comment: I tried all possibilities to get that work except this one! I would give you +10 if I could.

Comment: Need proc from Rails 3.1:
:conditions => proc { ["regra_fiscal = #{self.regra_fiscal}"]

(Yes, double quotes again :).

Comment: An additional single quote was necessary for me in Rails 3.2.13:

:conditions => proc { ["regra_fiscal = '#{self.regra_fiscal}'"] }

Comment: Better approach is to use bind variable to avoid SQL injection, i.e. `proc { ["regra_fiscal = ? ", regra_fiscal] }`

Comment: Now that you can't use :condition anymore in Rails 4 but -> { where column: true }, how would you update the accepted solution to work with Rails 4? (for now, Rails 4 only display a deprecation message)

Comment: I actually answered this in this very question http://stackoverflow.com/a/20412163/429941

Comment: Oh man, I would kiss you. Thank you very much good sir @Chirantan!

Comment: You can also return a hash from the proc.  Notice the double curly braces.  One set is the block of the proc and the other is for the hash.  `Proc.new{{:regra_fiscal => regra_fiscal}}`

Answer (score 65):

**Rails 4**+ way:

```
has_many :faixas_aliquotas, 
         -> (object){ where("regra_fiscal = ?", object.regra_fiscal)},  
         :class_name => 'Fiscal::FaixaAliquota'
```

Comment: I could not make it work (with has_many) passing an object as parameter. Isn't it used with scopes?

Comment: Worked fine for me! (I have no idea of what I'm doing)

Comment: nice, but had to put a comma

Comment: @brauliobo after object.regra_fiscal)} ?

Comment: Worked for the latest Rails. Thanks

Comment: I have been looking for this forever! Thank you so much! Seems like passing the object to the where block shouldn't be needed. I wish I could just use self there.

Answer (score 9):

There is another kind of solution. However, this wont be the default scope.

```
has_many :faixas_aliquotas, :class_name => 'Fiscal::FaixaAliquota' do 
  def filter(situacao_fiscal)
    find(:all, :conditions => {:regra_fiscal => situacao_fiscal.regra_fiscal})
  end
end
```

This way you would be able to do

```
situacao_fiscal.faixas_aliquotas.filter(situacao_fiscal)
```

I am not sure if this is elegant and something that would solve your problem. There may be better ways of doing this.

Comment: This is awesome and still works in Rails 5. This is great because I can use for association condition not only the object itself.

Answer (score 5):

**Rails 4+** another way:

```
has_many :faixas_aliquotas, -> (object){ where(regra_fiscal: object.regra_fiscal) }, :class_name => 'Fiscal::FaixaAliquota'
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 3.1 need to use proc, Proc.new { "field = #{self.send(:other_field)}" }

Comment: I had to use a proc, not a lambda to get this to work.  Thanks!

Comment: @Adam lambda works if you make it accept 1 arg. I have no idea what this arg is used for; I've only seen `nil`. Or you could use a lambda with variable args: `->(*args) { ... }`

Comment: As Harish Shetty commented on another answer, it's better to use bind variables to guard against sql injection: `proc { ['field = ?', self.send(:other_field)] }`

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3.1 you can use Proc.new for your conditions. as stated by @Amala, but instead generate a hash like this:

```
has_many :faixas_aliquotas, :class_name => 'Fiscal::FaixaAliquota',
   :conditions => {:regra_fiscal => Proc.new { {:regra_fiscal => self.regra_fiscal} }
```

The benefit of this approach is that if you do `object.faixas_aliquotas.build`, the newly created object will automatically have the same `regra_fiscal` attribute as the parent.