# ActiveRecord has_many with user-defined conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have an Account model that has many Entries, and I want to load the Account's entries only when it happens within a period.  This period is different for each user session so my `account.rb`  :

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :detail, :name
  attr_accessible :startDate, :endDate # not persisted in db
  has_many :entries, :order=>'date1,transref', :conditions => { :date1 => "#{@startDate}".."#{@endDate}" }

def startDate=(sd)
@startDate = sd
end

def startDate
@startDate
end

def endDate=(ed)
@endDate = ed
end

def endDate
@endDate
end

end
```

And my accounts_conttoller.rb:

```
def show
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  @account.startDate = '2012-02-01' #Actual value to be read from session[]
  @account.endDate = '2013-02-01' #Actual value to be read from session[]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @account }
  end
end
```

When i invoke `"show"`, `@account.entries` is empty and the SQL query used was:

```
SELECT ... WHERE entries.date1 BETWEEN '' and '' ...
```

The `startDate` and `endDate` became empty.  Where was my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the conditions in a `proc` so that they are evaluated dynamically, each time you call `entries`:

```
has_many :entries, :order=>'date1,transref', :conditions => proc { { :date1 => "#{@startDate}".."#{@endDate}" } }
```

I'd also recommend using the getter methods you defined (`startDate` and `endDate`), rather than directly accessing instance variables (generally considered bad practice):

```
has_many :entries, :order=>'date1,transref', :conditions => proc { { :date1 => "#{startDate}".."#{endDate}" } }
```

See also: [Rails has_many with dynamic conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462203/rails-has-many-with-dynamic-conditions)

Answer (score 1):

when you defining

```
has_many :entries, :order=>'date1,transref', 
  :conditions => { :date1 => "#{@startDate}".."#{@endDate}" }
```

your `@`-variables are **class (or singleton) variables**, and in `def show` they are **instance variables**

so you have to use smth like

```
@entries = self.entries.where( :date1 => @startDate..@endDate )
```

in your **show** method. And then, in view(s) access these entries using `@entries` instance variable