# How do you give extra criteria for associations?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

According to the Rails Guide, in Rails 4.0.x, you could do:

```
has_many :requests, -> { where status: false }
```

How would I do the same in Rails 3.2.x? Would I have to do an association extension? It's easy to associate tables in regards to one column, but when you want to filter based on two columns (for example, the foreign key being user_id, but wanting only those whose status column is false).

Comment: Question that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462203/rails-has-many-with-dynamic-conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
has_many :requests, :conditions => {:status => false}
```