# Scope ActiveRecord Relation based on record data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

I a model like this:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :career_clubs
  has_many :careers, through: :career_clubs
end
```

Which appropriately gets careers through the table `career_clubs`. So far this is only using the club's `id` field and getting all the records in the `career_clubs` table with that `id`.

What I actually want this to do, is use both the `id` and `organization_id`, so that it gets all the `career_clubs` with matching `id` and `organization_id`.

I know how to scope things using static data like below, but that doesn't seem to work here.

```
has_many :career_clubs, -> { where active: true }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails has\_many with dynamic conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462203/rails-has-many-with-dynamic-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
has_many :career_clubs, ->(club) { 
  where(club_id: club.id, organization_id: club.organization_id)
}
```