# How can I access a model's instance variable within a has_many association scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to scope a `has_many` relation of a model, by the model's instance variable.

I have a model like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, -> { where(product_type: @product_type) }
  attr_accessor :product_type
```

Then I'd do something like this:

```
category = Category.find(id)
category.product_type = 'type'
category.products # expected output: SELECT * FROM `products` ... WHERE `product_type` = 'type'
```

In the snippet give, the problem is that the scope is trying to get `@product_type` from the `ActiveRecord::Relation` and not the model itself.

How do I make it work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
has_many :products, :conditions => proc { "product_type = #{self.product_type}" }
```

You can check this out also: [Rails has_many with dynamic conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462203/rails-has-many-with-dynamic-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

What about if you pass `object` through the `scope`

```
has_many :products, ->(object) { where(product_type: object.product_type) }
```

Or Pass the `product_type` directly

```
has_many :products, ->(product_type) { where(product_type: product_type) }
```

Sources: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many