# Rails has_one conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I defined has_one relationship in drivers table

```
has_one :current_haul
```

It is associated with hauls table.
And hauls table and drivers table, both of them has `organization_id`.

I would like to apply the conditions like this

```
select * 
from drivers 
join hauls on drivers.organization_id=hauls.organization_id
 and drivers.current_haul_id= hauls.id
```

I can I put this conditions in `has_one` modifier ?

Comment: Have you checked [Active Record Associations docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-one)? For making it a dynamic condition you can use lambdas like illustrated in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2462397/2116518).

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can do it, simply add a boolean column on the `Haul` table. Maybe you will need a unique index to make sure you do not have multiple *currents* at any given moment.

`has_one :current_haul, -> { where(current: true) }, class_name: 'Haul'`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a association like below in your driver model.

has_one :current_haul, -> { where(current: true).first }, class_name: 'Haul'

Here i am assuming that a boolean bit is present in your Haul model to check the current status.