# Rails 5 Dynamic Conditions for has_many

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many

Been looking everywhere for an answer to this.

```
has_one :region_location, ->(location)  { where("region_locations.site_id = ?", location.current_site.id) if location.current_site }
```

This code is generating the following exception in my development environment.

> "The association scope 'region_location' is instance dependent (the
>   scope block takes an argument). Preloading instance dependent scopes
>   is not supported."

It seems like something that was possible in Rails 4 but not in 5 ([Rails has_many with dynamic conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462203/rails-has-many-with-dynamic-conditions))? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I thought about making it an instance method instead however I also use the association below.

```
has_one :region, :through => :region_location
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just make it an instance method instead. e.g.

```
def region_location  
  RegionLocation.find_by_site_id(self.current_site.id) if self.current_site
end
```

and the second part could just be

```
delegate :region, to: :region_location, allow_nil: true
```

That should solve this issue for you while maintaining the same functionality

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. Definitely slows things down though because with sunspot solr I can't do an :includes anymore with relationships defined this way.

Comment: @BenScheib hmmm that's a little tougher. might have to dig into rails source to find a solution