# Covering belongs_to condition to Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading a Rails 3 app to rails 5.1. In Rails-3 model I have a condition like

`has_one :current_contract, :class_name => 'Contract', 
:conditions => Proc.new { "contract_vw.country = '#{country_id}'" 
if country_id }`

I guess previous developer follow this hack

https://makandracards.com/makandra/983-dynamic-conditions-for-belongs_to-has_many-and-has_one-associations

I am not sure how to convert it to Rails 5.1

Any help appreciated.

Comment: do the methods for raisl 4 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462203/rails-has-many-with-dynamic-conditions work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails 4+ way is to write the scope like so:

```
has_one :account, -> (country_id) { where('contract_vw.country = ?', country_id) }, class_name: 'Contract'
```

You've written the `if country_id` *into* the association though, which seems real weird to me. Although `where('contract_vw.country = ?', country_id) if country_id` might work, I'd probably extract that into a method like:

```
def country?
  country_id.present?
end
```

And then, wherever you need it:

```
@model.account if @model.country?
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use-case correctly you're not bound to using `has_one` and in this instance I think it should not be used, use a regular method instead.

```
def current_contract
  contracts.where("contract_vw.country = ?", country_id).first if country_id.present?
  # or ...
  contracts.find_by(country: country_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. As I am upgrading atm, I not sure how it will impact the system. I am trying to make minimal changes.