# Assign user model to one of two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I have a user model that I want to assign to be teacher or student( teacher and student are two separated model ) because if the user signup he would have different registration fields depending on if he is teacher or student. User can be a teacher or student, not both.

I have tried, but don't think that this is the best way to do it. Any help?

```
class User < AR
  has_secure_password

  has_one :teacher, class_name: "teacher", foreign_key: "teacher_id", conditions: { role: 'teacher' }
  has_one :student, class_name: "student", foreign_key: "student_id", conditions: { role: 'student' }

  enum role: [:teacher, :student]
end

class Teacher < AR
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "user", foreign_key: "user_id"
end

class Student < AR
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "user", foreign_key: "user_id"
end
```

Comment: Use full-form for `AR` in your code snippet. Mention rails version as it smells like old version by optional parameter `conditions` provided in association method. Also you do not need to provide `class_name` & `foreign_key` as rails consider them by conventions.

Comment: ApplicationRecord, 5.2.0 rails I know that conditions are deprecated, but what else to use?

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2462203/10522579

Comment: Using Single Table Inheritance must be a good option in your case.

Comment: Using the Single Tabel Inheritance you will get 3 models: User, Teacher, and Student, but it will be all 1 table and you can differentiate the type of the user through the form ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can implement the STI for your case

```rb
class User < AR
  has_secure_password

  # Make all forms with User data send params with ':user' as a param key
  # instead of ':user_teacher'/':user_student'
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, 'User')
  end
end

class Teacher < User
  # custom methods 
end

class Student < User
  # custom methods
end
```

This way, you can have your form with `form_for @user do # ...`.

One caveat, it is all placed in the Single table in the DB (hence the name Single Table Inheritance), and that means a lot of NULL values for the unrelated fields (say `Teacher` has a `teacher_identification_number`, and a user has `student_identification_number` which are different in size or they require different validation) for all the Students that attribute `teacher_identification_number` would be NULL, and vice-versa.

If the fields are much different between the two models, then you can analyze your data and put it in the different table to which only the Teacher/Student would have access to, that is called a Database Normalization (say `Teacher` `has_many` `ClassInfo`'s or `has_one` `JobInfo`; or `Teacher` `has_one` `TeacherProfile`, and `Student` `has_one` `StudentProfile` or whatever).

It all really depends on how you model your DB.

References:
 - [Blog Post - Medium - STI](https://medium.com/@dcordz/single-table-inheritance-using-rails-5-02-6738bdd5101a)
 - [Video Link - Drifting Ruby - STI](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/single-table-inheritance)
 - [Video Link - @ RailsCasts - STI](http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations)
 - [Blog Post - StudyTonight - DB Normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)